# When run a "text file output" from Pentaho-Spoon, but some values are not output

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, spoon

I want to create a file that executes SQL results.
So, I create a transformation that consists of 'Table input - Text File output'. But it isn't working.
If I see the "Table input - Preview rows", all columns are clearly printed, even the null value as I want.
But some columns in the created text file are filled with a null value if even one row in a column has a null value. I don't know why. Please comment to me.

-- Expected

```
open a created text file
---------------------------------------
COLUMN_NAME1       COLUMN_NAME2
'N'                Hello World1
                   Hello World2
                   Hello World3
```

-- Result

```
Table input - preview rows
---------------------------------------
COLUMN_NAME1       COLUMN_NAME2
'N'                Hello World1
                   Hello World2
               Hello World3

open a created text file
---------------------------------------
COLUMN_NAME1       COLUMN_NAME2
                   Hello World1
                   Hello World2
                   Hello World3
```

Comment: I suggest to revise the Text file output fields. Can you add some more infos, like the type of columns in both the table and how are indicated in the Text output step?

Comment: I'm sorry for to late reply. We decided to handle that matter another way, so we deleted that try. Thank you for taking the time to reply to solve the problem. I wish you all the best in the new year.